# How to access pipeline options within Par.Do transforms?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

TL;DR: How can I access parameters passed to the job at job creation time in my Par.Do transforms?

I have two templates, one for Dev and one for Prod and they all work fine, except there is one value that needs to be different in each template. So far I've been "hardcoding" this value then I "run" java program to build the template (using the DataflowRunner runner). But this is error prone and if I'm not really really careful I will try to update some code in the dev template and inadvertently still have this value set from the prod template. Not good.

So, I thought the Pipeline Options would be good, I just pass in a different parameter, either at template compile time or even at template run time, but I am having a bear of a time accessing the value within the Par.Do transform where I need it. 
It works fine if I use the default runner and run the pipeline locally, but when I switch over and build the template, the value is always `null`. I can reproduce this with the following code:

```java
/* 
imports...
*/

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StarterPipeline {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StarterPipeline.class);

  static String orgId;

  public interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {


     @Description("Org Id")
     @Default.String("123-984-a")
     String getOrgId();
     void setOrgId( String orgID );

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {


     PipelineOptionsFactory.register(MyOptions.class);


     final MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs( args ).withValidation().create()
        .as( MyOptions.class );


     orgId = options.getOrgId();

     LOG.info( "orgId: " + orgId );

     Pipeline p = Pipeline.create( options );


     PCollection<String> someDataRows = p.apply("Get data from BQ", Create.of(

      "string 1", "string2", "string 3"

     ) );


     someDataRows.apply( "Package into a list", ParDo.of( new DoFn<String, String>() {

           @ProcessElement
           public void processElement( ProcessContext c ) {

              LOG.info( "Hello? " );
              LOG.info( "ORG ID: " + orgId );
           }

           }));


    p.run();
  }
}
```

The output in the cloud is:

```
 2018-09-20 (16:16:49) Hello?
 2018-09-20 (16:16:49) ORG ID: null
 2018-09-20 (16:16:51) Hello?
 2018-09-20 (16:16:51) ORG ID: null
 2018-09-20 (16:16:53) Hello?
 2018-09-20 (16:16:53) ORG ID: null
 ...
```

But locally:

```
Sep 20, 2018 4:15:32 PM simplepipeline.StarterPipeline main
INFO: orgId: jomama47
Sep 20, 2018 4:15:35 PM simplepipeline.StarterPipeline$1 processElement
INFO: Hello? 
Sep 20, 2018 4:15:35 PM simplepipeline.StarterPipeline$1 processElement
INFO: ORG ID: jomama47
Sep 20, 2018 4:15:35 PM simplepipeline.StarterPipeline$1 processElement
INFO: Hello? 
Sep 20, 2018 4:15:35 PM simplepipeline.StarterPipeline$1 processElement
INFO: Hello? 
Sep 20, 2018 4:15:35 PM simplepipeline.StarterPipeline$1 processElement
INFO: ORG ID: jomama47
Sep 20, 2018 4:15:35 PM simplepipeline.StarterPipeline$1 processElement
INFO: ORG ID: jomama47
```

These are the build parameters I'm using for the template:

```
--project=the-project
--stagingLocation=gs://staging.the-project.appspot.com/staging/
--tempLocation=gs://staging.the-project.appspot.com/temp/
--runner=DataflowRunner
--region=us-west1
--templateLocation=gs://staging.the-project.appspot.com/templates/NoobPipelineDev
--orgId=jomama47
```

And for local:

```
--project=the-project
--tempLocation=gs://staging.the-project.appspot.com
--orgId=jomama47
```

I tried passing parameters to the job when I created the job in the Dataflow console (browser) in the parameters fiels as `orgId` and `jomama77`, but it still comes out as null.

Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things here. First of all, I would recommend using [`ValueProvider`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/ValueProvider.html) so that you can pass the parameter at runtime for different `orgId`:

```
public interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {    
     @Description("Org Id")
     @Default.String("123-984-a")
     ValueProvider<String> getOrgId();
     void setOrgId(ValueProvider<String> orgID);   
}
```

Then read it from options with:

```
ValueProvider<String> orgId = options.getOrgId();
```

For this to be accessible within the ParDo you can pass it as a parameter to the constructor such as the example in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-pipeline-options):

```
someDataRows.apply( "Package into a list", ParDo.of( new CustomFn(orgId)));
```

where `CustomFn`'s constructor takes it as an arguments and stores it in a `ValueProvider` so that it's accessible from within the ParDo. Notice that now you'll need to use `orgId.get()`:

```
static class CustomFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
    // access options from wihtin the ParDo
    ValueProvider<String> orgId;
    public CustomFn(ValueProvider<String> orgId) {
        this.orgId = orgId;
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement( ProcessContext c ) {
      LOG.info( "Hello? " );
      LOG.info( "ORG ID: " + orgId.get() );
    }
}
```

Now you can stage the template and call it with:

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs run $JOB_NAME \
    --gcs-location gs://$BUCKET/templates/$TEMPLATE_NAME \
    --parameters orgId=jomama47
```

This should work as expected:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for such a well written answer. The links to the docs were very helpful and I appreciate the time you took to put this together. It works great, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `ValueProvider` is certainly a possibility (see answer by Guillem), but you can simplify your code by simply using the value directly:

```
public interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {    
     @Description("Org Id")
     @Default.String("123-984-a")
     String getOrgId(); // Actual type here
     void setOrgId(String orgID);   
}

static class CustomFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
    // This will serialize (String is Serializable)
    private final String orgId;
    public CustomFn(String orgId) {
        this.orgId = orgId;
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      LOG.info("ORG ID: " + orgId);
    }
}
```

All data stored in the `DoFn` instance, which is not `transient` needs to be `Serializable`. `String` and all primitive types are. `ValueProvider` payload also needs to be `Serializable`.

You can also get the options directly in your `DoFn`:

```
static class CustomFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      LOG.info( "ORG ID: " + c.getPipelineOptions().as(MyOptions.class).getOrgId();
    }
}
```